# svn branch (removed .svn folders)

Tags: java, svn

I did a few things wrong while merging trunk into a branch. First I thought it's easier to checkout a new working copy of the trunk and add all changes "by hand". Then I thought it's ok to remove the branched "src" folder and overwrite it with the "src" from the trunk. Now it's clear that the .svn folders aren't the right folders (as they belong to the trunk instead of to the branch). So I decided to delete all .svn folders, but now I don't know how it's easiest to add it to the branch once again or how to create a new branch with all my changes.

I suppose I did everything wrong so far...

I think I will disconnect my project, checkout the head revision of the branch, but then again I somehow want to "override" the branch, that is more or less replace the whole "src"-folder (standard maven layout).

Well it's more or less that I can disconnect my changes from svn, which is essentially the current state ("src" is not a working copy, as such I can also disconnect everything). Alternatively I have a copy without the removed .svn folders, but the .svn folders point to the trunk, that's the whole problem.

kind regards,
Johannes

Comment: Are you using the "standard" svn layout with `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags`? Is everything committed, or do you have local changes? Which version of `svn` are you using?

Comment: Have a look at `svn switch` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html). This may help in your scenario.

Comment: I've so many changes, that I first thought about "real" merging, but then ended up using the trunk and added my changes to it, then I thought I could copy it over, but yeah... yes we use the standard svn layout. My branch is a Java7 branch and the trunk uses Java6.

Comment: Then I'd just use `svn merge`, i.e. restart the merging process.

Comment: Restarting? Hell, no, I needed 3 full days, about 12 working hours each day ;-) I would rather create a new project and merge changes like I've done now and create a new project everytime I have to merge :D :-/ hell, what a disaster...

Comment: How do I get a working copy _with_ my changes done on the trunk, but in my branch? Maybe it's the simplest thing to create a new branch from the working copy with all the .svn folders from the trunk with my merges? (And then really merge regularly)?

Comment: the last hope would always be to do a svn import, thus loosing your change history. Is your "broken" directory still a valid working copy (can you call svn status on it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps that I use when I want to replace something from another branch into another branch or whatever (under Windows):

1) checkout latest copy of the original branch from the SVN server. Let say this is the original copy {A}

2) make a copy of your working copy. Let say this is the modified copy {B}

3) change directory to the root of your {B} and remove hidden .svn folders from all folders and subfolders of {B}

```
CD "{B}"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G"
```

4) copy {B} to {A}

5) commit {A}

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've also thought and what I've done, plus deleted some obsolete classes before 5) ;-) And a little shell commando to delete the .svn directories ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to discard all the changes that were made on the branch, and replace it with the exact code that's on the trunk.  In that case, why not just remove the whole branch, and create a new one based on the current state of the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

The 5 step plan by @eee should help you integrate your working copy changes into SVN (either Trunk or a Branch).

If you're looking to upgrade your branch with changes from Trunk, you might consider the "Bunny Hopping" method described here: http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/

Basically, create a new branch from Trunk, merge your old branch into the new branch, and then delete your old branch. If you have uncommitted, working-copy changes, you can then copy those into a new working copy.

Note that with a SVN 1.7 client, it's much easier to remove the .svn folders, as there's only 1 in the root of the working copy.

Comment: I've still svn, version 1.6.12 (r955767) compiled Aug  5 2011, 17:07:24 from Ubuntu ;-)