# TortoiseSVN v1.7 - error while upgrading working copy folder from v1.6

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I upgraded `TortoiseSVN` from 1.6 to 1.7. So to use it I needed to upgrade working copy folder.

But while upgrading it shows messageBox with error:

> Can't open directory
>   'D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\project\WEB-INF\classes\.svn\text-base':
>   System cannot find specified path

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: @DaveHogan cleanup says: `D:\SVN_HOME>svn cleanup
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy 'D:\SVN_HOME' is too old (format 10, created by Subve
rsion 1.6)`

Comment: Strange - sounds hacky, but how about creating the folder?

Comment: @DaveHogan creating works, but I need to create like thousands of them)

Comment: What about `svn checkout` from scratch? (If you don't have any pending commits, of course)

Comment: @IgorKorkhov unfortunately, there is a lot of commits are pending)

Comment: @VextoR: then maybe commit your changes using svn 1.6?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov too late) because svn working folder is half upgraded already, so it's neither 1.6 nor 1.7, it's like a Frankenstein now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having read through all the comments to the original question, I would propose the following steps.

1. **Backup** the contents of D:\SVN_HOME
2. Checkout your source tree into a different folder, say SVN_HOME_NEW
3. Copy every modified file in SVN_HOME to a corresponding sub-folder of SVN_HOME_NEW, replacing the original files under SVN_HOME_NEW
4. Check in your changes to SVN_HOME_NEW

Comment: You can also use WinMerge (http://winmerge.org/) to compare your original folder contents and the newly checked out.

Comment: I agree with the general logic here but you should elaborate more on step 3 - how does one "copy every modified files"? I think it's much better to copy and exclude the `.svn` directories using `rsync --cvs-exclude` though

Answer (score 0):

A SVN working copy is just a copy with `.svn` folder in every folder and sub-folder of a project you are working on. They are used to keep track of whatever pending changes made to the project content. These `.svn` folders can be deleted, leaving a project files with the latest modifications that you haven't committed yet to the central SVN repository/server.

TortoiseSVN 1.7 uses these `.svn` folders to a point that they are no longer compatible with the older TortoiseSVN versions. In no way it will affect the Subversion server and repository when the local copy's `.svn` folders are stripped off.

My solution as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534049/svn-branch-removed-svn-folders/8534791#8534791) will make sure whatever that have not been committed yet from a corrupted/tainted copy that have been stripped off its `.svn` folders can be copied into a new working copy pulled from TortoiseSVN 1.7 to be committed later. The reason for the tainted copy needs to be stripped off its `.svn` folders is that when it is copied into a fresh untainted copy, the "good-looking" `.svn` folders in the untainted copy won't be overwritten as so to maintain the last good state of the untainted copy from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one directory that is complaining and you know what is modified or if nothing was modified you can always try to delete that directory and then do the upgrade and afterwards do an update and everything is back normal. So I solved it here.

Answer (score 0):

The `.svn` folders in
 
`D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\project\WEB-INF\classes\`
are probably a copy of the folder that probably resides in 
 `D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\project\WEB-INF\src\`.

Eclipse or your build script has probably copied the `.svn` folders from `src` into `classes` when compiling the project.

You could delete all the `.svn` folders out of the classes folder that have been placed there incorrectly and try the update again.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue resolved to me with the following steps.

- Import your project to eclipse
- right click --> select Team --> Share
- Follow the steps and give your correct repository URL.
- Once it sync completed then you will get upgraded svn and also able
  to take folder update.

Good Luck...